# How to grep and sort from JSON file by specific word?

Tags: ruby, json

I have the following JSON file:

```
{
  "opscenter_adhoc_2014-02-03-12-34-16-UTC": {
    "keyspaces": {
      "test": {
        "nodes": [
          "10.242.214.188",
          "10.62.77.47",
          "10.244.15.39"
        ],
        "cfs": {
          "test": "/var/lib/cassandra/data/test/test/snapshots/opscenter_adhoc_2014-02-03-12-34-16-UTC"
        }
      }
    },
    "id": "adhoc",
    "time": 1391430856
  },
  "opscenter_adhoc_2014-02-03-13-16-04-UTC": {
    "keyspaces": {
      "test": {
        "nodes": [
          "10.242.214.188",
          "10.62.77.47",
          "10.244.15.39"
        ],
        "cfs": {
          "test": "/var/lib/cassandra/data/test/test/snapshots/opscenter_adhoc_2014-02-03-13-16-04-UTC"
        }
      }
    },
    "id": "adhoc",
    "time": 1391433364
  },
  "opscenter_adhoc_2014-02-03-11-32-06-UTC": {
    "keyspaces": {
      "test": {
        "nodes": [
          "10.242.214.188",
          "10.62.77.47",
          "10.244.15.39"
        ],
        "cfs": {
          "test": "/var/lib/cassandra/data/test/test/snapshots/opscenter_adhoc_2014-02-03-11-32-06-UTC"
        }
      }
    },
    "id": "adhoc",
    "time": 1391427126
  }
```

I'd like to grep the file by `opscenter_adhoc_2014-02-03-11-32-06-UTC` only where `2014-02-03-11-32-06-UTC` is timestamp of backup and than sort the list by timestamps to get the latest timestamp.
Tried in Ruby by using

```
File.readlines("/tmp/out.txt").grep(/opscenter_adhoc/)
```

which returns me all the string but I need just only `opscenter_adhoc_TIMESTAMP` list

Comment: And what have you tried?

Comment: ss = File.readlines("/tmp/out.txt").grep(/"opscenter_adhoc_.*UTC/)
But it returns whole line which contains "opscenter_adhoc", I need just only the list of opscenter_adhoc_TIMESTAMP

Comment: @AntonRadkevich Please, update the question with the code you have tried, don't post it as a comment.

Comment: Also please provide the result you expect to get within your post.

Comment: @mudasobwa
I expect to get sorted result like:
"opscenter_adhoc_2014-02-03-13-16-04-UTC"
"opscenter_adhoc_2014-02-03-12-34-16-UTC"
"opscenter_adhoc_2014-02-03-11-32-06-UTC"

Comment: @Anton, Please edit the question to include that.  The question should contain everything needed for someone to answer it.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you correctly, you are expecting to get sorted array of dates. Here you go:

```
require 'json'
JSON.parse(File.read('/tmp/qq.json')).keys.sort

# ⇒ => [
#        [0] "opscenter_adhoc_2014-02-03-11-32-06-UTC",
#        [1] "opscenter_adhoc_2014-02-03-12-34-16-UTC",
#        [2] "opscenter_adhoc_2014-02-03-13-16-04-UTC"
# ]
```

Comment: @Anton If this answer was helpful to you, please up-vote it, and give it the checkmark.